# VBScript Execute and Eval Commands

Tags: vbscript

I have a vbscript that will read in commands from a text file. I am thinking of using the Execute and Eval commands to execute the commands from the file. Obviously, I will read in the file as a string, and parse the string into Eval and Execute commands. However, I am not sure if this is possible, and how to go about doing it?

For example, let's say I have the following file:

```
x = 3
y = 4
z = x + y

Print z
```

In my vbscript, I want something like the following:

```
' Read in file to string
' Split the string at the newline (commandList)
For Each str in commandList:
    Execute(str)
Next str
```

The output would be:

`7`

I have tried the following to get a proof of concept:

Execute("x = 1")

However, I keep getting a "Function terminated during evaluation" error. Not sure what I am doing wrong. I am not too familiar with vbscript.

Comment: Are you _sure_  your question is on `vbscript`? Please [edit] your question and show your text file containing _commands_ to be executed and an adequate code snippet (refer to [ask]).

Comment: Can't reproduce "Function terminated during evaluation" error (using cscript.exe) so probably something other than a mistake in `Execute("x = 1")`. Tried changing one of the spaces to a non-breaking space (U+00A0), got "Syntax Error". Tried defining a function/sub x(), got "Illegal assignment". Tried presetting x to an object, just overwrote it with the value. I suspect a clue might be in the sample input. Which host environment provides a "print" statement? Perhaps it is the environment that doesn't like the Execute statement.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best explanation is here: [Link-1](https://ss64.com/vb/execute.html)
In short, `Eval()` command takes an expression and returns its value, while
`Execute()` command takes a group of statements and executes them (in global scope  I think).
In general, `Eval()` expects some result of expression, while `Execute()` doesn't. 
For detailed explanation see the link above.
Paul

Comment: 1) `Eval` doesn't expect the **result** of an expression. It expects a string representation **of** an *expression* and returns the result of evaluating that expression. Similarly, `Execute[Global]` expects a string representation of a statement list and executes it (them). Note that, in VBScript, an expression by itself is **NOT** a statement and cannot be evaluated by `Execute[Global]`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63748437/13760977) answer for a detailed explanation.

Comment: 2) `Execute` runs in local scope, `ExecuteGlobal` runs in global scope.

Answer (score 0):

Your concept seems to be right.

```
==>type D:\VB_scripts\SO\29832173.vbs
option explicit
Dim commandList(2), str
commandList(0)= "x = 3"
commandList(1)= "y = 4"
commandList(2)= "z = x + y"
For Each str in commandList
  Execute str
Next
Wscript.echo x, y, z

==>cscript D:\VB_scripts\SO\29832173.vbs
3 4 7

==>
```

[Explanation (Execute vs. Eval)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z5x4094(v=vs.85).aspx):

In VBScript, `x = y` can be interpreted two ways. The first is as an assignment statement, where the value of `y` is assigned to `x`. The second interpretation is as an expression that tests if `x` and `y` have the same value. If they do, the result is `True`; if they are not, the result is `False`. The `Eval` method always uses the second interpretation, whereas the `Execute` statement always uses the first.

**Edit** with regard to [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/47824472?noredirect=1): *This is giving me a type mismatched error when getting in the For loop.*  With some additional debugging `echo` and with `For Each` loop changed to `For...Next` iteration:

```
==>type D:\VB_scripts\SO\29832173.vbs
option explicit
Dim commandList(2), str, ii
commandList(0)= "x = 3"
commandList(1)= "y = 4"
commandList(2)= "z = x + y"
For ii = 0 To UBound( commandList)
  Wscript.Echo "To execute: " & commandList( ii), CStr( Eval( commandList( ii)))
  Execute commandList( ii)
  Wscript.Echo "  Executed: " & commandList( ii), CStr( Eval( commandList( ii)))
Next
Wscript.Echo x, y, z

==>cscript D:\VB_scripts\SO\29832173.vbs
To execute: x = 3 False
  Executed: x = 3 True
To execute: y = 4 False
  Executed: y = 4 True
To execute: z = x + y False
  Executed: z = x + y True
3 4 7

==>
```

Comment: This is giving me a type mismatched error when getting in the For loop.

Comment: It is still telling me the "Function terminated during evaluation" on the Execute line. If I add triple quotes around the commands ("""COMMAND"""), I do not get the error, but nothing prints out.